# flattening of nested json using spark scala creating 2 column with same name and giving error of duplicate in Phoenix

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatten

I was trying to flatten the very nested JSON, and create spark dataframe and the ultimate goal is to push the given dataframe to phoenix. I am successfully able to flatten the JSON using code.

```
def recurs(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  if(df.schema.fields.find(_.dataType match {
    case ArrayType(StructType(_),_) | StructType(_) => true
    case _ => false
  }).isEmpty) df
  else {
    val columns = df.schema.fields.map(f => f.dataType match {
      case _: ArrayType => explode(col(f.name)).as(f.name)
      case s: StructType => col(s"${f.name}.*")
      case _ => col(f.name)
    })
    recurs(df.select(columns:_*))
  }
}
val df = spark.read.json(json_location)
flatten_df = recurs(df)
flatten_df.show()
```

My nested json is something like:

```
          {
           "Total Value": 3,
           "Topic": "Example",
           "values": [
                      {
                        "value": "#example1",
                        "points": [
                                   [
                                   "123",
                                   "156"
                                  ]
                            ],
                        "properties": {
                         "date": "12-04-19",
                         "value": "Model example 1"
                            }
                         },
                       {"value": "#example2",
                        "points": [
                                   [
                                   "124",
                                   "157"
                                  ]
                            ],
                        "properties": {
                         "date": "12-05-19",
                         "value": "Model example 2"
                            }
                         }
                      ]
               }
```

The output I am getting:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|Total Value| Topic     |value     | points      | date                   |    value               |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 3         | Example   | example1 | [123,156]   | 12-04-19               |    Model example 1     | 
| 3         | Example   | example2 | [124,157]   | 12-05-19               |    Model example 2     |       
+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

So, value key is found 2 times in json so it is creating 2 column name but this is an error and not allowed in Phoenix to ingest this data.

The error message is:

> ERROR 514 (42892): A duplicate column name was detected in the object definition or ALTER TABLE/VIEW statement

I am expecting this output so that phoenix could differentiate the columns.

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|Total Value| Topic     |values.value  | values.points | values.properties.date | values.properties.value|              |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 3         | Example   | example1     | [123,156]     | 12-04-19               |    Model example 1     | 
| 3         | Example   | example2     | [124,157]     | 12-05-19               |    Model example 2     |       
+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

In this way phoenix can ingest the data perfectly, please suggest any changes in flattening code or any help to achieve the same. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, do you expect "values" to be a simple prefix for column names or a structure containing attributes (points, value, ...) ?

Comment: Hi @baitmbarek, actually values is the key where the nested JSON is present. For different JSON it could be anything, reportValues and under it all the nested JSON and in that case every column name shall be reportValues.value, reportValues.points etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need slight changes to the `recurs` method:

1. Dealing with `ArrayType(st: StructType, _)` instead of `ArrayType`.
2. Avoid using *, and name every field in the second match (`StructType`).
3. Use `backticks` at the right places to rename the fields, keeping precedence naming.

Here's some code:

```scala
def recurs(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  if(!df.schema.fields.exists(_.dataType match {
    case ArrayType(StructType(_),_) | StructType(_) => true
    case _ => false
  })) df
  else {
    val columns = df.schema.fields.flatMap(f => f.dataType match {
      case ArrayType(st: StructType, _) => Seq(explode(col(f.name)).as(f.name))
      case s: StructType =>
        s.fieldNames.map{sf => col(s"`${f.name}`.$sf").as(s"${f.name}.$sf")}
      case _ => Seq(col(s"`${f.name}`"))
    })
    recurs(df.select(columns:_*))
  }
}

val newDF = recurs(df).cache
newDF.show(false)
newDF.printSchema
```

And the new output:

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------+
|Topic  |Total Value|values.points|values.properties.date|values.properties.value|values.value|
+-------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------+
|Example|3          |[[123, 156]] |12-04-19              |Model example 1        |#example1   |
|Example|3          |[[124, 157]] |12-05-19              |Model example 2        |#example2   |
+-------+-----------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------+

root
 |-- Topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Total Value: long (nullable = true)
 |-- values.points: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- values.properties.date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values.properties.value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values.value: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi @baitmbarek Thanks for the answer. I tried this code but it seems that it breaking somewhere. like in my data there is one root key reportData and error it gives org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`reportData.shifts`', somewhere it's not taking full column name eq. values.properties.value but just properties.value

Comment: Meanwhile thanks for the suggestion, I'll try further to understand and implement the code.

Comment: Hi @baitmbarek, Your solution works great for having key with Array and inside there could be Array value like Array -> Array and other key-value pairs, but fails in some cases. Like JSON with 1)  Array -> Struct and other key-value pairs. 2) Array -> Array having struct data + other key-value pairs. 3) Struct -> Array

Comment: Can you please help me to change some minor issue with the code. Otherwise, it's giving me error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve `value.somecolumn`. Any help will be appreciated.